# In python Matplotlib.pyplot in hist() I want to select xlabel and ylabel value

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, histogram, visualization

I used those libraries :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I import data
and then I select what I want to study

```
df=df15[['Country','Happiness Score']][0:5]
df
```

The output was

```
    Country Happiness Score
0   Switzerland 7.587
1   Iceland 7.561
2   Denmark 7.527
3   Norway  7.522
4   Canada  7.427
```

after that I want to use plt.hist()
I want to be x=Country and y= Happiness Score??

Answer (score 0):

You could set the country as index and create a pandas bar plot. Note that a bar plot shows values for a label, while a histogram arranges many values into bins and shows the height of each bin. The concepts look similar but have a different goal.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_str = '''    Country Happiness_Score
0   Switzerland 7.587
1   Iceland 7.561
2   Denmark 7.527
3   Norway  7.522
4   Canada  7.427'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index('Country').plot(kind='bar', rot=0, legend=False)
plt.ylabel('Happiness Score')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

Histogram are used to see the distribution of single variable.
Which in your case is Happiness Score. putting an x label as 'Country' in histogram won't make sense.

A bar char would make more sense with  x=Country and y= Happiness Score.